# jaggery command line script does not execute the jaggery script in the argument

Tags: wso2, jaggery-js

I tried writting some jaggery expressions in a separate .jag file and tried executing it as follows

```
./jaggery.sh file.jag
```

The output is just the content in the file. Whatever i have in the file is printed to the console.

i.e if i have

`print("hello");` in file.jag

the output is `print("hello");` whereas my expected output is `hello`

Comment: What's the version of jaggery-js?

Comment: 0.9.0 snapshot. I think it is the latest

Comment: Can you please add the content of your file.jag here too?

Comment: i have just one line "print("hello")" as mentioned above in the question

Comment: okay. the issue was from my side. i hadn't included the tags <% %>

Answer (score 0):

Try like following

```
<%
   print('hello');
%>
```

And, [It's mentioned that](http://jaggeryjs.org/quickstart.jag),

> Jaggery CMD is still experimental, and is for developer preview. You
>   are welcome to play with it and please do provide us your
>   [feedback](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/JAGGERY)